# Move to the end or beginning of the current line in VI when in insert mode

Tags: linux, vi

I am not proficient with my knowledge of VI editor and find it troublesome to keep pressing the `-> (Right Arrow)` key to move to the end of the line

While searching on google I found that `exiting the insert mode` and then pressing the `$` key will move the cursor to the end of the line. It works fine, but I will still want to be able to move the cursor to the end of the current line or the beginning while in `insert` mode.

Any help with it is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple

<kbd>End</kbd> will force the cursor to the end of the line  and <kbd>Home</kbd> will force the cursor to beginning of the line in `Linux VI editor`

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>End</kbd> in **Linux**, and <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>right arrow</kbd> in **OSX**.